# WireShark cannot find packets for my port

Tags: wireshark

I made a CSharp tcp server and the server listened the port 8888.
I can connect that server with telnet by port 8888, but when I use wireshark to see packets to my server using filters, it finds no result..

I am using Windows, how do I see packets to my server?

Thank you for reading.

I am looking forward to seeing your wise answers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide little details on your capture setup, but very likely you're not setup correctly, so I would recommend that you check your [capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).